# sql mulitple checkbox OR query statement

Tags: sql

How would I use this in a query with multiple selections it would have to be something like

```
SELECT * FROM venue_event where venue = $check or $check ??
```

Form

```
 <form action="test.php" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
 <?php
 if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
 foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know php well enough to post that part, but your SQL query should end up looking like:

```
SELECT *
FROM venue_event
WHERE venue IN ('venue1','venue2');
```

Or you can use OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM venue_event
WHERE venue = 'venue1' OR 
    venue = 'venue2';
```

Comment: If I was using the php code I provided above how would I separate the $check vales in the query you provided? Or am I going all about this the wrong way? I just want a form you can select multiple check box's and query the vales from my database.

Comment: If you give all your checkboxes the same name, when the form is submitted you will either have a list of values or nothing whatsoever.  That's why the first suggestion by @sgeddes is a good one.  However, you have to have a plan for form submissions with no checkboxes checked.

Comment: I found a solution: <?php 
$options = Array();
foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $i)
   $options[] = 'venue=' . "'$i'"; // don't forget to escape $i somehow!

$sql = "SELECT * FROM venue_event";
if (count($options))
   $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $options);

echo $sql;
 

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>

Comment: @user2072272 -- glad you could get it to work.  Sorry I couldn't help more with the PHP side :)